# Magento 2: How to define scope in di.xml & Router.php

Tags: magento2, php, module, custom, routing

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.0.

**app\code\Custom\Module\etc\frontend\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_module" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Custom\Module\Controller\Router</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">22</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="CustomModuleRoutingEntityPosts" type="custom\module\Model\Routing\Entity">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="prefixConfigPath" xsi:type="const">Custom\Module\Model\Posts\Url::URL_PREFIX_CONFIG_PATH</argument>
            <argument name="suffixConfigPath" xsi:type="const">Custom\Module\Model\Posts\Url::URL_SUFFIX_CONFIG_PATH</argument>
            <argument name="factory" xsi:type="object">Custom\Module\Model\PostsFactory</argument>
            <argument name="controller" xsi:type="string">posts</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Custom\Module\Controller\Router">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routingEntities" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="posts" xsi:type="object">CustomModuleRoutingEntityPosts</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

For Defining Scope there will be `<argument name="defaultScope" xsi:type="string">posts</argument>` Global, Frontend, Primary i have seen.

I would like to put condition in `di.xml` if there is particular URL http://localhost/magento2/mymodule/test.html then only it will call this di.xml file otherwise not.

I have created custom `Router.php`, when i call Magento 2 Default Category/Product List then also it goes to my custom `Router.php`, So what's the best way so it's limited to my Custom Module Only.

I'm following https://github.com/tzyganu/Magento2SampleModule/blob/master/Controller/Router.php

When i do

```
 public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request) {
     echo 1;exit;
 }
```

Each & every Request call this custom router. Which i think not correct. So that's why it needed to define Scope for `Router.php` via `di.xml` or Any other Magento Standard way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible to conditionally add router or define that url XXX will be served by this router only.

However i believe there is a way to minimize your problem. In your `di.xml`, you define sortOrder for the router.

Looking at `\Magento\Framework\App\RouterList` you will see that magento sorts the routers by this information.

In `\Magento\Framework\App\FrontendController`

you can see how the route is looked up:

```
while (!$request->isDispatched() && $routingCycleCounter++ < 100) {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface $router */
        foreach ($this->_routerList as $router) {
            try {
                $actionInstance = $router->match($request);
                if ($actionInstance) {
                    $request->setDispatched(true);
                    $this->response->setNoCacheHeaders();
                    if ($actionInstance instanceof \Magento\Framework\App\Action\AbstractAction) {
                        $result = $actionInstance->dispatch($request);
                    } else {
                        $result = $actionInstance->execute();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException $e) {
                $request->initForward();
                $request->setActionName('noroute');
                $request->setDispatched(false);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Magento goes over the sorted routers, until one of them dispatches the request and then stops. So ideally you want to have as high sort order as possible, so you router is called almost last.

I said almost, because i think CMS module should be last, since it takes care of 404 page. (not tested what happens)

For instance CMS module uses router sort order 60 and the catalog module you mentioned uses 40 (This is in `Magento_Url_Rewrite` i assume). You use 22 so your router will run first.

I would say if you set sortOrder higher than 40, you should be getting decent results.

Alternatively there are plugins. You can create plugin and do your magic in code. Especially `dispatch()` function in FrontendController seems like a decent place.

Comment: So it's thing only related to sortOrder?

Comment: It really depends on what are you trying to achieve, but yes. The sortOrder attribute determines which Router gets executed first, second and so on.

Comment: This answer is useful for me , by using sortOrder node i have managed to change router loading flow like this `1. Catalog Product  2. Custom Router 3. CMS router `.  For a Custom router i have used sort order as 50.